# SQL - How to determine why a stored procedures sometimes takes many times longer than usual

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

We have a recently implemented data warehouse and reporting solution. Generally, the process of pulling the information together takes around 8 minutes.

About once per day, one particular stored procedure takes much longer (~2 hours) than expected.  There is no rhyme or reason to the time of day, and usually the next run will proceed normally, making this harder to track down.

So far, I've used the profiler to find which stored procedure is taking longer than expected, and have the [expected execution plan.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18416400/datExecPlan.csv)

How can I figure out why this happens?

Comment: Do you have solution implemented for **Parameter Sniffing**? It is possible that some parameters are causing bad execution plans.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I don't, I'll look into that. I'm honestly pretty new to SQL in general, sort of a inherited role. Reading up on it now, thanks for the help. I'll let you know what I find!  


EDIT: The only parameter passed is something that is only used for logging purposes at the end of the stored procedure. Obviously recompiling won't help for that, but would recompiling help if data in some of the tables it uses changes?

Comment: Here is great blog to read on [Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx). In other cases if your SP has multiple path based on values with `IF THEN` statements that could also cause unstable execution plans. In many cases `WITH(RECOMPILE)` can improve it.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I don't think there are multiple paths to take, but I went ahead and added the WITH RECOMPILE flag. I'll report back tomorrow after monitoring for a day.  Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Still running into the issue unfortunately :(

Comment: I recently discovered [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp#pricing) tool. You can download free copy of it and just insert your SP into the tool. It will show you `Actual Execution Plan` that is very easy to read. Also it has option to `Anonymize`. than you can save it and post it.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Thanks, will do this and report findings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from the explain plan, you have 2 tables where you are doing an union all and then inserting the records.

I would split this into the following;

Have a temporary table which will represent the structure of the union all table.

```
1> Truncate the temporary table
2> Insert records from the first part of the union all query
3> Insert records from the second part of the union all query
4> restructure the actual insert to work from the temporary table
```

This should run multiple times faster;
you can use appropriate selection criteria (where clause) to limit the two inserts which will be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - when these changes are implemented I will report back with findings.